# How to Integrate this Ln function

Tags: calculus

Please advise how to integrate this function.  I think I need to use parts to do this, but I can't seem to get to the right answer.  I know what the final solution is supposed to be, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong in my effort to get there.

> $$\int \ln (1+2x)\:dx$$

Thanks in advance.
Marcia

Comment: Can you integrate ln(x)?

Comment: Use the by parts method

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: what happens when you substitute $u \equiv 1+2x$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One may integrate by parts as follows
$$
\int \ln(1+2x)\:dx=\frac{1+2x}2\:\ln(1+2x)-\int \frac{1+2x}2\cdot\frac{(1+2x)'}{(1+2x)}\:dx=\:?
$$